# Accessing record fields by their name in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, reflection

I want to know if there exists something like Reflection API in PL/SQL or not.

I have a table like

```
create table my_table (
  id number,
  value1 number,
  value2 number, 
  value3 number,
  value4 number,
  value5 number);
```

And I have a variable as

```
rec as my_table%rowtype
... fill rec

insert into my_table values rec;
```

is there any way I can populate `rec` field dynamically by its name.

I mean I know the index (in this case something between 1 and 5), so I want to set `'value'||index` to something.

As in my real case the last index is much more than 5, using a set of `if/elsif` is not proper. By the way number of fields is increased in long term (for example `value6`, `value7` ma be added next year and so on, so I wan to write some kind of code not to be changed on every new column).

Comment: you need dynamic sql for doing the same,if you share sample code on what you are trying to do we can help on the same

Comment: @psaraj12 I want to fill the `rec` and then insert it into table.

Comment: By the way is there any way I can do something like `execute immediate INSERT_QUERY using COLLECTION_VARIABLE`? When I write something like this, I get an error saying a COLLECTION_VARIABLE is not an SQL Type.

Comment: I think you have to create Type at the schema level

Comment: @psaraj12 dynamically? How?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375

Comment: Apparently your requirement is unclear but if you want to perform dynamic SQL on collection refer example 7.4 on the oracle documentation page - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/11_dynam.htm

Comment: DBMS_SQL. It all depends on how you fill out `rec`. This can be solved if it is possible to replace `rec` with the collection number for val1..val5 (next val1..val7).

Answer (score 0):

You can access variables in a program using dynamic SQL only if they are available globally.  If you declare you record in the spec you can build utility functions that will use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to build a small PL/SQL block to set the value.  Here is a simple example of what you are looking for.  Notice you can overload the set procedure to keep your datatypes intact.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  value1 NUMBER,
  value2 VARCHAR2(100), 
  value3 DATE);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_my_table IS
  my_table_rec my_table%ROWTYPE;

  FUNCTION build_statement(i_record IN VARCHAR2,
                           i_field  IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2;

  PROCEDURE set_value(i_record IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_field  IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_value  IN VARCHAR2);

  PROCEDURE set_value(i_record IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_field  IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_value  IN NUMBER);

  PROCEDURE set_value(i_record IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_field  IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_value  IN DATE);

  PROCEDURE insert_a_row;
END pkg_my_table;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_my_table IS
  FUNCTION build_statement(i_record IN VARCHAR2,
                           i_field  IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 'BEGIN ' || lower($$PLSQL_UNIT) || '.' || i_record || '.' || i_field || ' := :x; END;';
  END build_statement;

  PROCEDURE set_value(i_record IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_field  IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_value  IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE build_statement(i_record => i_record,
                                      i_field  => i_field)
      USING i_value;
  END set_value;

  PROCEDURE set_value(i_record IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_field  IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_value  IN NUMBER) IS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE build_statement(i_record => i_record,
                                      i_field  => i_field)
      USING i_value;
  END set_value;

  PROCEDURE set_value(i_record IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_field  IN VARCHAR2,
                      i_value  IN DATE) IS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE build_statement(i_record => i_record,
                                      i_field  => i_field)
      USING i_value;
  END set_value;

  PROCEDURE insert_a_row IS
  BEGIN
    my_table_rec := NULL;
    set_value(i_record => 'my_table_rec',
              i_field  => 'value1',
              i_value  => 42);
    set_value(i_record => 'my_table_rec',
              i_field  => 'value2',
              i_value  => 'forty-two');
    set_value(i_record => 'my_table_rec',
              i_field  => 'value3',
              i_value  => to_date('1/1/1942',
                                  'mm/dd/yyyy'));
    INSERT INTO my_table
    VALUES my_table_rec;
  END insert_a_row;
END pkg_my_table;
/

BEGIN
  pkg_my_table.insert_a_row;
END;
/

SELECT *
  FROM my_table;
-- 42   forty-two   1/1/1942
```

Beware globals: you need to reset them correctly before using them again or you might get data carried over from previous invocations.  Setting an entire record type variable to NULL will reset all the underlying fields (handy).

You will also be prone to ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded errors should you compile PL/SQL with globals where there are active sessions referencing your code.  Generally this is not a problem, but it is a behavioral difference.